# Css class on a render section

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to apply a certain css class to all icons under a specific render section?

```
@section NavBarContentRight {
```

I have icons under this sepcific section and I want to make sure all the icons are font-size: 21px.

We use this render section on a lot of views.

Just curious if I can set it once somewhere so I do not have to go find all icons under that section etc.

Comment: Wouldn't `@section` just render output as like `<div id="section">` so you could just do `#section i { font-size: 21px!important }`

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, I think this is the answer:  .navbar-content-right .svg-inline--fa {
    font-size: 21px !important;
}  I have to use .svg-inline-fa... for font awesome because the <i> is replaced to the svc etc.